# MySQL updating where not in one column to four columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - coverage and import.  They're linked by a company_id.  The coverage table has one coverage type per row.  The import table has up to 4 columns of coverages.

[image]

The default on i_coverage_1 through 4 is null.  What I need to do is update the coverage.c_cov_end date to the current date if the coverage.c_coverage is not in the import coverages 1-4 for that company.

This query *seems* to work (as a select anyway), at least on my small test data set, but I don't now about the efficiency when this import table hits 50,000 rows.

```
SELECT c.c_id, c.c_coverage, c.c_company_id
  FROM coverage c
 WHERE c.c_cov_end IS NULL
   AND NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 1
        FROM import i
       WHERE (c.c_coverage = i.i_coverage_1 OR 
              c.c_coverage = i.i_coverage_2 OR
              c.c_coverage = i.i_coverage_3 OR
              c.c_coverage = i.i_coverage_4 OR
             )
         AND c.c_company_id = i.i_company_id
    );
```

Comment: Create 50K rows with fake data and run a test. However - It doesn't look efficient. Concider to normalize the `import` table.

Comment: I don't believe there's much that I can do with normalizing the data as it's coming from a system we have no control over.  I guess I could create a temporary table and insert the company and coverages into that row by row and then do a left join to deactivate old coverages.

Comment: Do you mean you can't modify the schema at all? Can you create indexes?

Comment: I can alter my schema and create indexes, but the import file will be coming in 4x per month in a fixed format that gets dumped into that import table.  I think I might go the temp table route and just insert the company id and imported coverages into a temp table - one coverage per row - so I can then do my new coverages and drops from that.

Comment: You can create an insert trigger for the `import` table, which will populate the normalized table (it shouldn't be temporary). But I'm not sure any more if that is a good idea. The relation between the tables isn't clear. Does the `import` table have no PK? And is `company_id` unique in any of the tables?

Comment: Yes, i_id is the PK for the import table - I just omitted it for clarity.  company_id should be unique in import since they're sending all data for a given company on one row.  In coverage it's not unique since that's a one-to-many relationship to the actual company table.

Comment: If `i_company_id` is unique, then I don't see any way to make your query much faster. You will need to scan the entire `coverage` table either way. However - `i_company_id` should be indexed. And you can rewrite your condition to `c.c_coverage IN (i.i_coverage_1, i.i_coverage_1, ...)`. But that shouldn't make any difference in performance.

Comment: Paul Spiegel - I wish I could mark your first comment as the answer!  I tried a large scale test normalizing the imported data into a 2nd temporary table and it worked like a charm.  if you want to write an answer as that I'll accept it.